# get e.target.files[0]; in click event jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to use images on canvas, so I do

```
document.getElementById('file').addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        var file = e.target.files[0];
        console.log(file) //worked
    });
```

But how can I e.target.files[0] from image element within clicks event?

```
$('.img').click(function(){
//what to do here?
})
```

Comment: An image element has no files property. Explain in more detail exactly what you want to accomlish

Comment: @charlietfl but my img has src which is the url right? I expect when I click on a image, I can get the e.target.file[0] or base64 format.

Comment: Your comment says `e.target.file[0]`, but your code sample says `e.target.files[0]`.

Comment: `this.src` is the url...from there read up on using images in canvas

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, simply use filereader api.

```
function toDataUrl(url, callback) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.responseType = 'blob';
      xhr.onload = function() {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function() {
          callback(reader.result);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(xhr.response);
      };
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.send();
    }
```

and I can do

```
toDataUrl('http://example.com/abc.png', function(data) {
console.log(data)//base64
})
```